# The images not showing from SQLite when store it as URL

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

When retrieving the images from Firebase to SQlite it comes as link, so I am trying now to show the images through Picasso as the following:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(favoritesList.get(position).getFoodImage())
    .into(viewHolder.food_image);
```

but the image not showing. why its not showing? and how can i solve this issue?

Comment: Are you getting imageUrl from this favoritesList.get(position).getFoodImage()

Comment: Does that *URL* working in browser ?

Comment: yes its there and working properly. but not showing as image

Comment: @AmrSoliman What is the *URL* looks like ? Can you post it ?

Comment: @JayRathodRJ its like this link: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/eat-it-recipe.appspot.com/o/images%2Fmeat.jpg?alt=media&token=3162810a-1d38-47e1-98aa-c7dcb302074e

Comment: @JayRathodRJ when i checked again, i found the result is all letters caps lock, maybe this is the issue !!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and used Glide it is latest ..
add below dependency into app level gradle file..

```
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
```

and make sure your path is not empty for give firebase server ..

```
          Glide.with(context).load(favoritesList.get(position).getFoodImage())
                .into(viewHolder.food_image);
```

and adapter define constructor like below ..

```
public RecyclerViewAdpater(List<String> mStringList, Context mContext) {
    this.mStringList = mStringList;
    this.mContext = mContext;
}
```

Comment: still same issue,  i found the result of the URL is all letters caps lock, maybe this is the issue !!!

Answer (score 0):

You are using old library try this,

In Gradle

```
  implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

In Java

```
Picasso.get()
.load(url)
.placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
.error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
.into(imageView);
```

[See more details Here.](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Comment: if don't get any exception try like this, before 
 add"http://"+favoritesList.get(position).getFoodImage()

Answer (score 0):

Set Image from URL using Picasso like this

```
Picasso.with(context)
                .load(favoritesList.get(position).getFoodImage())
                .resize(width,height).into(viewHolder.food_image);
```

**OR**

Load Image from direct URL

```
URL url = new URL(favoritesList.get(position).getFoodImage().toString());
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
viewHolder.food_image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Hope this may help you

Comment: still same issue,  i found the result of the URL is all letters caps lock, maybe this is the issue !!!